# How to display value of another fields of related field in Odoo form views

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-15

is that possible to display value of another fields of related field? For example, by default, in Sale Order, the displayed value of `partner_id` is the value of `partner_id.name` .. how if I want to display value of `partner_id.mobile` instead of their default?

I've tried explicitly declare `"partner_id.{FIELD}"` like this one below, but the SO model always detects that those fields are not available in the model :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <record id="sale_order_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">sale.order.form.inherit</field>
        <field name="model">sale.order</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.sale_order_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <notebook position="inside">
                <page string="BSP Prinsipal" name="bsp_prinsipal_page">
                    <group>
                        <field name="partner_id.cp_logistik"/>
                        <field name="partner_id.cp_finance"/>
                        <field name="partner_id.cp_marketing"/>
                    </group>
                </page>
            </notebook>
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

Thanks in advance, by the way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use dotted field names in the form view. You can use a related field and remove `partner_id` from the field name

***Example:***

- Inherit sale order model:

  ```py
  class SaleOrder(models.Model):
      _inherit = 'sale.order'

      cp_logistik = fields.Float(related="partner_id.cp_logistik")
      cp_finance = fields.Float(related="partner_id.cp_finance")
      cp_marketing = fields.Float(related="partner_id.cp_marketing")
  ```
- Use related field names in form view:

  ```xml
  <record id="sale_order_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
      <field name="name">sale.order.form.inherit</field>
      <field name="model">sale.order</field>
      <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.sale_order_form"/>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
          <notebook position="inside">
              <page string="BSP Prinsipal" name="bsp_prinsipal_page">
                  <group>
                      <field name="cp_logistik"/>
                      <field name="cp_finance"/>
                      <field name="cp_marketing"/>
                  </group>
              </page>
          </notebook>
      </field>
  </record>
  ```

*. You may need to modify the field types*

Comment: Wow! This one just works perfectly! Big big big thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can inherit [`name_get()`](https://www.cybrosys.com/blog/how-to-use-of-name-get-function-in-odoo) method in the `res.partner` model and change it so that it displays the string you want. Something like this (adjust what you need to).

```
class ResPartnerInherit(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    def name_get(self):
        result = []
        for rec in self:
            result.append((rec.id, '%s' % (rec.mobile)))
        return result
```

Note: This modification will affect the name display of this model everywhere in the system.